# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database. [Python] [sqlite]

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I am using a common function to execute all sqlite queries in a class. It all works, until I use a for loop with more than one item in the list.

Here's the common function that executes sqlite queries:

```
def executeQuery(self, query, params = ()):
        results = {}
        try:
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(query, params)
            self.conn.commit()
            rows = cur.fetchall()

            results['status'] = 'success'
            result = []
            if rows:
                column = map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description)
                for row in rows:
                    result.append( dict(zip(column, row)) )

            results['results'] = result

        except self.conn.Error, e:
            if self.conn:
                self.conn.rollback()

            print "Error: %s" % e.args[0]
            results['status'] = 'failure'
            results['results'] = e.args[0]

        finally:
            if self.conn:
                self.conn.close()

        return results
```

And here's the loop that gets me the database closed error:

```
stages = self.getStageByDate(2000)
        for stage in stages['results']:
            print stage['name']
            additives = self.getStageAdditives(stage['name'])
            print additives
            for additive in additives['results']:
                print additive
```

Error seems to originate from the `getStageAdditives()` as it return 4 items, while `getStageByDate()` return only 1.

It seems to me like the connection to the database is not closed before the second connection is attempted. Why does this happen? It did not happen when used with MySQL database. What are the solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 15):

You write "It seems to me like the connection to the database is not closed before the second connection is attempted" but, in fact, there is no "second connection" to the database.  You're using a single connection, which I'm guessing is created in the initializer (`__init__`) for the not-shown-in-your-example class that contains the method `execute_query`.

You (again guessing) create the `conn` in that `__init__` method, but you close it immediately after executing any query.  Therefore, it will not be available when you execute another query.

Instead, you should not `.close()` but rather `.commit()` at the end of your query.  Don't do this in `finally` but rather at the end of the `try`.  That way the transaction will either be committed (if it succeeds) or rolled back (in the except block, if it fails).

Then, add a separate `.close()` method to your larger class which in turn calls `.close()` on the connection, and have the calling program call *that* method when it's finished with all its queries.  That call to close would appropriately appear in a `finally` block inside the larger program.

Comment: Ah, it was pure chance it didn't cause an issue before. Is having one connection for the entire class ok, or maybe I should open/close the connection in executeQuery()? The connection is created in the __init__ of the same class as the code I posted. There's already a commit in try, I don't think it should be at the end since there's no point to proceed to process data if query has failed.

Comment: It depends on how long you intend to keep that class around and whether you're doing any kind of threading.  The objects you create of that class will not be threadsafe, every thread will need it own connection.  But if you're not threading and are careful to always close the object when you're done with it then it's find to have one connection for the lifetime of the object (and, indeed, that's how I do it).

Comment: And yes, I did miss the commit statement.

Comment: I will have some threading but it will call methods from this class, will that cause problems? Does creating new connection each time cause problems (performance is not a big concern)?

Comment: In my experience, you cannot share a connection across threads.  This will lead to database locking errors.  Therefore, you cannot create one of these objects and share it globally among threads.  But if each thread creates its own one of these objects and closes it when done, you should be okay.

Comment: The thread would create a new instance of the class that creates database connection, does that mean that essentially a new connection is created for the thread or would this still cause an issue? Bit confused...

Comment: If the `__init__` method of the object creates the `connection`, and each thread creates it's own instance of the object then you would be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Remove this from code

```
 self.conn.close()
```

It will resolve the problem because when you want to retrieve information from database you cannot write

> conn.close()

Answer (score 0):

Why is a business method closing the connection? Surely it should close the cursor instead? Closing the connection would mean that the second time the `executeQuery` is called, it would fail because the connection is gone.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by business method but the rest makes sense. Can you post a quick sample for clearness?

Comment: @DominicM In this case, `executeQuery` is the “business method”. And no, I can't; I don't know Python well enough to write a good example. (I _do_ know the SQLite API, but principally in other languages.)

Comment: You were on the right track but no, you cannot close a cursor  as there's not close() method for a cursor. I just needed to remove the conn.close() altogether.