# SQLite "SELECT" - function returns empty data-array 2nd time in loop

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, while-loop

I stumbled across a problem while experimenting with Data storing and plotting from different sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi.
In the following script I try to SELECT data from my SQLite-database to plot a  graph.
Because I want my graph to be updated each minute with the recent data I put it in a *while True:* Loop.
My problem is, that it works perfectly the first time but at the second iteration it returns an empty plot.

I checked using `print(data)` and the reason for the empty plot is that it returns nothing after the first iteration.

I am certain it is because I have to establish my connection to the database again somehow after every iteration.

But I've tried using

```
#     conn = sql.connect('/home/pi/Documents/autofarm/sqlite/sensorLog.db')
#     cr = conn.cursor()
```

At the start of the function instead of importing it: `from connectDB import *`. But this is not helping.

I also tried to close the connection and/ or cursor at the end  of every iteration using

```
    #cr.close()
    #conn.close()
```

This did not work at all I just got the error : *sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.* after the first iteration.

My code:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/bin/python3')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/pi/Documents/autofarm/sqlite/')
from connectDB import *
# import sqlite3 as sql

dpiSet = 62

def plotDaily():
#     conn = sql.connect('/home/pi/Documents/autofarm/sqlite/sensorLog.db')
#     cr = conn.cursor()
    today = datetime.now()
    today1 = today.strftime('%x')
    day = today.strftime("%-d-%-m-%y")
    cr.execute('SELECT * FROM DATALOG WHERE [date] = ?', (today1, ))
    data = cr.fetchall()
    print(data)
    time = []
    humidity = []
    temp = []
    for row in data:
        time.append(row[1])
        humidity.append(row[3])
        temp.append(row[2])
        
    plt.plot(time,temp)
    plt.title(today1 + " Temperatur")
    plt.ylim(0,45)
    file1 = "/home/pi/Documents/autofarm/sqlite/plotData/"+str(day)+"_temp.png"
    plt.savefig(file1, dpi = dpiSet)
    plt.clf()
    
    plt.plot(time, humidity)
    plt.title(today1 + " Luftfeuchtigkeit")
    plt.ylim(10,90)
    plt.show()
    file2 = "/home/pi/Documents/autofarm/sqlite/plotData/" +str(day)+"_hum.png"
    plt.savefig(file2, dpi = dpiSet)
    plt.clf()
    #cr.close()
    #conn.close()
   

        
    
# plotDaily()
    


while True:
    plotDaily()
    sleep(60)
```

I hope the problem is described clearly and I appreciate every help and piece of advice.
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23048489/13964629

Comment: First, thank you posting the link. I've read it and even though it is not quite the same problem it led me to rearrange some of my code. For example I put the connection in an own function and  separated the SQL query from saving the plot. Unfortunately I could not fix the problem but I found out the actual problem. When I am looping just the SQL query it always catches the data, but as soon as I try to plot the data it returns empty again after the first iteration. I am an amateur but I really tried and researched a lot and I have no idea why the plot is interrupting the SQL query